# Are you sure you want to shut down your computer now?

Tags: keyboard, shutdown, damage

Unless I keep <kbd>alt</kbd> keyboard button pressed, the MacBook gets shutdown! After a few seconds of releasing the <kbd>alt</kbd> button, a message is popped up saying:

> Are you sure you want to shut down your computer now?
>
> Reopen windows when logging back in
>
> Restart | Sleep | Cancel | Shut Down

This is a MacBook from 2009. **Water** poured on the top-right section of the keyboard. Afterwards, it gets shutdown unless the <kbd>alt</kbd> keyboard button is pressed continuously! Did anybody run into this issue before?

---

Also, when booting, the <kbd>alt</kbd> button needs to pressed. Otherwise, the MacBook gets shutdown while booting ...

### Update

A colleague cracked open the MacBook, he did nothing, and put it together. Afterwards, surprisingly, the MacBook was working good for a couple of days! But got crazy again.

The behavior looks random. Sometimes it doesn't get shutdown for a couple of days and sometimes it shuts down frequently.

Comment: What kind of answers do you expect to get? Seems rather obvious that the water damage impacted some contacts on the top-right section of the keyboard, so how exactly can we help you here?

Comment: @nohillside I'm just trying desperately I guess :(

Comment: Did you do anything to dry or remove the water? Or just waited?

Comment: @SolarMike I tried to make it dry ... after being turned-on for a while, now the MacBook works even without `alt` button being pressed ... not sure why

Comment: @SolarMike So far so good ... I don't turn off the MacBook for now ... I'm afraid it would go bad again!